# Java help JOptionPane Madness

Tags: java, dropbox, joptionpane

Really needing help on this have been trying for the past hour playing around and can't seem to get it. Have looked for the question online and getting a lot of solutions that are similar but not quite accomplishing the task would appreciate if someone could help me with this?

I am currently working on a dropBox API and am trying to create a JOptionPane that prompts the user to enter the code generated from dropBox API and the program to read the input and verify.. I have done the System.in with success but this is for a GUI so obviously not helpful.

```
System.out.println("Enter Your auth code in this prompt and hit enter and wait..");
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Code Here: ");
String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();

// Want JOptionPane to function the same way this ^ would behave

String info = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(code +" test " );
if(code == null){
    System.exit(1);
    return;
}
code = code.trim();
// This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code.
DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);
String accessToken = authFinish.accessToken;
DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);
System.out.println("Linked account: " + client.getAccountInfo().displayName);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello..."+
    client.getAccountInfo().displayName+
    "     And Welcome To Our Community!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String 'result' should hold the code they entered into the JOptionPane.

**EDIT #1:**

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your auth code here:"); //Prompt for the auth code.  
//If they didn't enter anything into the JOptionPane then close the program with code 1.
if (result.isEmpty()) {
    System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println(result.trim()); //For testing purposes print the trimmed auth code to console.
// [Omitted Code] //
```

Also, you  don't need to call return after a System.exit(#) because the program will never get to that code anyway.

Comment: I may not have understood what you were looking for, if so please clarify and I will update my answer.

Comment: Hey Sir Jacob, thanks for the response. Essentially I'm just trying to get the code to act the same way the ' System.In ' is in the sense of validating the user input. System.in works 100% fine but I'm just trying to achieve the same results with the JOptionPane and not really sure how to do this as I'm just spinning my wheels modifying stuff..

Comment: What is the exact purpose of the JOptionPane linked to the info var?

Comment: the info var is dead code sorry didn't mean to confuse you. just basically want this         ******String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();*****      in a form of a JOptionPane.showInputDialog      So the user would enter the key from Drop Box he/she has enter it in push OK and the program to run through and achieve the same result that the System.in accomplishes

Comment: Thank you for all your help. My program is running nice with that little bit of code you gave me edit #1 :)

Comment: It's my pleasure to help! Don't forget to my my answer as the correct one.